# BitConverter.IsLittleEndian on Mono/Mac OS returns true

Tags: c#, macos, mono, endianness

I've used both a console app and the Mono C# REPL to test this, and I get `true` in both cases. I was under the impression that `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian` would report the endianness of the underlying system. Shouldn't this return false when running on Mac OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intel based macs are little endian, PowerPC (unless very old) based macs will support switchable endianness.

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness